# Sort string array alphabetically and return index array without special library functions

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm a PLC programmer (Schneider Modicon M241) and looking for a solution to create an index array which lets me access a array of string alphabetically in a loop. As I don't have any fancy library for sorting tasks available I'll have to get away with simple loop and string compare algorithms.

My program runs a registration process of different objects. I'm saving the instance path of each object and the object type in a RegistryArray. Something like this with some dummy entries:

```
RegistryArray : ARRAY[0..ConstantMaxNumOfRegistryElements] OF RegistryStruct := [
(InstancePath := 'Programm.CoolingPump', ObjectType := 'Pump_1'),
(InstancePath := 'Programm.FeedstockPump', ObjectType := 'Pump_1'),
(InstancePath := 'Programm.AuxPump', ObjectType := 'AuxPump'),
.
.
.
(....lots of empty space for more registred objects...)];

Struct RegistryStruct
    InstancePath : String;
    ObjectType : String;
    NextAlphabeticalByName : INT := -1;
    NextAlphabeticalByType : INT := -1;
End_Struct
```

My RegistryArray should stay as it is. I only want to get an index array which tells me which index of the RegistryArray I have to access to go through the data alphabetically by ObjectType and InstancePath. The output would look like this when its sorted by the instance path:

```
IndexArray : ARRAY[0..ConstantMaxNumOfRegistryElements] OF INT := [2, 0, 1, ...(empty space is 0)];
```

I also want to store in each RegistryArray element the information which one is the next element I'll have to access when I want to step through the RegistryArray alphabetically by ObjectType or InstancePath, hence the members NextAlphabeticalByName and NextAlphabeticalByType are there. Like this:

```
RegistryArray : [
(...ObjectType := 'Pump_1', NextAlphabeticalByName := 1),
(...ObjectType := 'Pump_1', NextAlphabeticalByName := -1 (when FeedstockPump is the last in alphabetical order)),
(...ObjectType := 'AuxPump', NextAlphabeticalByName := 0),
.
.
.];
```

I need to sort this array after each new Object added in the RegistryArray. I have no control about how objects are added to this array. InstancePath and Type can be random and at a completely random order.

I'm unsure if a bubble sort approach is super efficient since I'll have to do the sorting after each new element by InstancePath and ObjectType. Can someone lead me to a better algorithm?

Comment: Bubble Sort is *never* "super efficient", though it can be efficient enough.

Comment: Insertion sort will be better than Bubble sort for all (or maybe almost all) cases. How large do you expect the array to be? Will the array start unsorted, or are you adding a small number of new entries to an already sorted array?

Comment: Array size is around 500. I'm only adding one item at a time and then sorting the array. The array starts by zero so it kinda starts "sorted".